# Strange behaviour when subclassing datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, timedelta

for convenience I want to create subclasses of datetime.timedelta. The idea is to define a class as such:

```
class Hours(datetime.timedelta):
    def __init__(self, hours):
        super(Hours, self).__init__(hours=hours)
```

so I can quickly create timedeltas like that:

```
x = Hours(n)
```

However, the code above produces a timedelta of n days instead of n hours. As an example, look at the following ipython session:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: class Hours(datetime.timedelta):
   ...:     def __init__(self, hours):
   ...:         super(Hours, self).__init__(hours=hours)
   ...:         

In [3]: print(Hours(10))
Out[3]: 10 days, 0:00:00
```

I'm not able to explain this. Is anybody?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use `__new__`, instead of `__init__`:

```
import datetime as DT
class Hours(DT.timedelta):
    def __new__(self, hours):
        return DT.timedelta.__new__(self, hours=hours)
x = Hours(10)
print(x)
```

yields

```
10:00:00
```

---

If you override `__init__`, but not `__new__`, then `DT.timedelta.__new__` gets called *before* your `Hours.__init__`. Notice

```
import datetime as DT
class Hours(DT.timedelta):
    def __init__(self, hours):
        print(self)

x = Hours(10)
```

prints `10 days, 0:00:00`. This shows that `DT.timedelta.__new__` has already set the timedelta to 10 days before you even get a chance to configure it in `Hours.__init__`.

Moreover, `DT.timedelta` is an immutable object -- you can't change the `days` or `seconds` or `microseconds` after the object has been instantiated. Python creates immutable objects by using the `__new__` method, and generally don't do anything in the `__init__` method. Mutable objects do the reverse: they configure the object in `__init__` and don't do anything in `__new__`.

---

Per [the docs](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#__new__):

> When subclassing immutable built-in types like numbers and strings,
>   and occasionally in other situations, the static method `__new__` comes
>   in handy. `__new__` is the first step in instance construction, invoked
>   before `__init__`. The `__new__` method is called with the class as its
>   first argument; its responsibility is to return a new instance of that
>   class. Compare this to `__init__`: `__init__` is called with an instance
>   as its first argument, and it doesn't return anything; its
>   responsibility is to initialize the instance....
>
> All this is done so that immutable types can preserve their
>   immutability while allowing subclassing.

(If immutable objects performed configuration in `__init__`, then you could mutate an immutable by calling `immutable.__init__`. Obviously, we don't want that, so `immutable.__init__` generally does nothing.)

---

Note also that unless you plan to add new methods to your `Hours` class, it would be simpler, and therefore better to just use a function:

```
def hours(hours):
    return DT.timedelta(hours=hours)
```

Comment: So, `datetime.timedelta` does it's initialization inside `__new__`?