# Why do I get this TypeError while using Python's copy.deepcopy?

Tags: python, deep-copy

I've just run into this error with `copy.deepcopy`:

```
import copy
import datetime


class Hours(datetime.timedelta):
    # Using __new__ because timedelta is immutable
    # See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22531773/3358488.
    def __new__(cls, hours):
        return datetime.timedelta.__new__(cls, hours=hours)


h1 = Hours(2)
h2 = copy.deepcopy(h1)  # TypeError: __new__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Here's the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxx/Documents/PyCharmProjects/Flow/backend/deepcopy_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    h2 = copy.deepcopy(h1)  # TypeError: __new__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
  File "/Users/xxxx/.conda/envs/qtdesktopapp/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/Users/xxxx/.conda/envs/qtdesktopapp/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 264, in _reconstruct
    y = func(*args)
TypeError: __new__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Note that [timedelta initialization](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)'s takes anywhere from 0 to 6 arguments:

```
class datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)
```

Have I used `copy.deepcopy` incorrectly or have I found a bug in it?

Comment: What is your intent with defining `__new__`? Evidently your signature for it is not correct. Are you confusing it for `__init__`?

Comment: @bgfvdu3w that's because timedelta is immutable, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22531773/3358488

Comment: Regarding the PPS, you get all the zeros because you gave the parameters default values of 0.

Comment: @wjandrea: but the method does capture a non-zero value when I use `*args`, so why aren't those non-zero values captured by the positional arguments. The default `0` should not be used if values are being provided...

Comment: @user118967 Sorry, I totally misunderstood! The actual reason is that the new parameters don't match the usage. `Hours(2)` means `Hours(days=2)`, but `days` is not saved anywhere. If you do `Hours(hours=2)` instead, you'll see `0 7200 0 0 0 0 0`.

Comment: @wjandrea: sorry, I still don't understand. It seems that somewhere `deepcopy` is calling `__new__` with `0 7200 0 0 0 0 0` arguments. If I use `*args*`, I capture that. But if I have all those positional arguments with default `0`, I only get `0`s, which I don't understand since the default should not kick in if `7200` is being provided.

Comment: @user118967 Sorry, I think you're confusing two different situations. If you add `print(h1); print(h2)`, it should be clearer, and [here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/9a5759f776969000195dd2217d58105e) with a full explanation.

Comment: @wjandrea I see! Thank you very much for taking the time to create the gist!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `*args` to your `__new__` and add a `print` so you can see what arguments it's getting called with:

```
import copy
import datetime


class Hours(datetime.timedelta):
    def __new__(cls, hours, *args):
        print(cls, hours, *args)
        return datetime.timedelta.__new__(cls, hours=hours)


h1 = Hours(2)
h2 = copy.deepcopy(h1)
```

prints:

```
<class '__main__.Hours'> 2
<class '__main__.Hours'> 0 7200 0
```

`deepcopy` doesn't know that you modified `__new__` so it's trying to construct a copy the same way it'd copy a `timedelta` object, by passing the positional args `days`, `seconds`, and `microseconds`.

If you want `deepcopy` to work correcty, you need to override the `__deepcopy__` method in your class to match the `__new__` override:

```
class Hours(datetime.timedelta):
    def __new__(cls, hours):
        return datetime.timedelta.__new__(cls, hours=hours)

    def __deepcopy__(self, _memo):
        return Hours(self.seconds // 3600)


h1 = Hours(2)
h2 = copy.deepcopy(h1)
assert h1 is not h2  # different objects
assert h1 == h2      # but they're still equivalent
```

Comment: This works in this case, but it doesn't work for negatives or partial hours. For example try `Hours(-1.501)`, which `timedelta` represents as `-1 day, 22:29:56.400000`. This solution reduces it to just `22:00:00`. I think it'd be better to lean into the parent constructor instead, i.e. `def __deepcopy__(self, _memo): return datetime.timedelta.__new__(type(self), self.days, self.seconds, self.microseconds)`.